# Scrapy LinkExtractor Specific Url

Tags: scrapy

i'm using to crawl a website. However, the current code redirects me and does not crawl from the URL I want.

URL: 
http://www.example.com/book/diff/ 
Where diff can be anything except /. 
To add on, I only want to crawl url that match the url.

Here is my current code:

```
 name = "testing"
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = [
    'http://www.example.com/book/',
]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^http://www.example.com/book/[^/]*/$')),
 callback='parse_page',follow=True),)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'^http://www.example.com/book/')), callback='parse_page',follow=True),)
```

This should be enough.